# Limit of a functional equation

Tags: limits, functional-equations

Starting from the function 
$$f(x) = ax+bf(xy)$$ 
where $x,a>0$, $0<b<1$, and $y>1$, and $y,a,b$ are fixed, I got 
$$f(x) = ax(1+by+b^2y^2+\ldots+b^{n-1}y^{n-1})+b^nf(xy^n)$$
I want to evaluate the limit of this function as $n \to \infty$. The first term is a geometric series so it's easy. My question is: how do I evaluate the limit of $b^nf(xy^n)$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: I just edited the question.

Comment: Is $y$ fixed ? Or can you chose it freely greater than 1 ?

Comment: This looks more like a functional equation to me. For a recursion you have some start instance and then successor instances. I fail to see this here.

Comment: @mvw I apologize. I don't know what kind of function is this so I just put there the quotation marks :D

Comment: @Astyx let me edit the question again

Comment: I guess $x$ being fixed is a typo ?

Comment: @Astyx Yup! Edited the question again :D

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function, assuming you meant that $y$ can be freely picked.

Let $x=1$. Then $f(1) = a+b f(y)$, so $f(y)$ is constant on $y > 1$, and equal to $\frac{f(1)-a}{b}$.

Note that $f(2) = 2a + b f(2y)$ for all $y > 1$, but $f(2) = \frac{f(1) - a}{b}$ and $f(2y) = \frac{f(1)-a}{b}$, so we have $$\frac{f(1)-a}{b} = 2a+f(1)-a$$
whereupon $$f(1)-a = b f(1)+a b$$
so $$f(1) = \frac{2a}{1-b}$$
That is, $$f(y) = \frac{a(1+b)}{b(1-b)}$$

Then $$f(3) = 3a + b f(3y)$$ so $$\frac{a(1+b)}{b(1-b)} = 3a+\frac{a(1+b)}{1-b}$$
which reduces to $b=\frac{1}{2}$; so $f(y) = 6a$ for $y>1$.

Finally, $$f(4) = 4a+b f(4y)$$
so $6a=4a+3a$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance, but how does it help to evaluate the limit?

Comment: @CaesarIanPedro It tells you that the function is constant on $y>1$, so the limit is just that constant value. However, it turns out that this function can't exist, unless I've made some horrible error or misinterpreted you.

Comment: Actually, I got this function from a research paper in finance. I tried to derive it on my own but I got stock on evaluating this limit. The authors skipped so much step and they implied that the limit of that term is 0.